# Volume vs setVolume

Tags: objective-c, syntax, methods

I was looking through the developer documentation and found two methods which seem to do the same thing, but I couldn't tell the difference between them.

For example in `NSSound`:

```
[mySound volume];
```

and

```
[mySound setVolume:0.2];
```

what would be the outcome of these two pieces of code?

I know that the latter sets the volume to what I want it to. I set it to `0.2`; if I go higher, the volume is increased, obviously, but what about the first example?

What does that do, where I would use these separately, and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C Methods and syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375179/objective-c-methods-and-syntax)

Comment: They're asking different things, Josh.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375179/objective-c-methods-and-syntax

Comment: Try to extrapolate from the answers you got to that earlier question, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case 'volume' is a property of the mySound object.  You are right, in the second example you are setting that property to 0.2.  The first example is the getter for that property. It will return the current value of volume to you.  For example if you did this:

```
[mySound setVolume:0.2];
float newVolume = [mySound volume];
```

The value in newVolume would be 0.2.

Answer (score 1):

It is a so called "getter" and returns the current value of `mySound`'s `volume`. You would typically call it by assigning the return value to a variable:

```
float currentVolume = [mySound volume];
```